# How to issue a new compile command in Makefile.am?

Tags: makefile, autotools, automake

I am building a library (using Autotools) that looks like the following. The building of the library works fine when I add a *.cpp file to `libmytest_la_SOURCES`.

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libmytest.la

libmytest_la_SOURCES = test.capnp.c++

libmytest_la_CXXFLAGS = -I/usr/include -I$(top_srcdir)/src/includes 

libmytest_la_LDFLAGS = -version-info 0:0:0 -L/usr/lib64

libmytest_la_LIBADD = -lcapnp
```

The problem is that I need to call a third-party compiler to generate code before doing the normal compile process. The following `capnp` tool will generate a c++ output file named `test.capnp.c++`.

```
capnp compile -oc++ test.capnp
```

And if I plug the output of that (`test.capnp.c++`) into the makefile above, my library is built. What I don't get is how to invoke that command into the Makefile.am to generate the needed source file and plug it into the `libmytest_la_SOURCES` variable.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automake does not have direct support for `capnp`, and adding support for a new language or tool would involve hacking the program.  But you *can* provide ordinary `make` rules in your `Makefile.am` file, and these will be carried through to the final generated `Makefile`.  This is Automake's primary extension point.

Thus, you might add this to your Makefile:

```
test.capnp.c++ : test.capnp
     capnp compile -oc++ $<

# or
#    $(CAPNP) compile -oc++ $<
# where $(CAPNP) is the capnp binary as discovered by configure
```

You would want to also designate `test.capnp` as an additional file to distribute:

```
EXTRA_DIST = test.capnp
```

---

You should also consider whether you want the .c++ file to be included in distribution packages, to relieve the build-time dependency on `capnp`.  If not, then instead of listing it in `libmytest_la_SOURCES` you should list it in `nodist_libmytest_la_SOURCES`, plus also in `CLEANFILES`:

```
#
# test.capnp.c++ is a built file that we choose not to distribute
#
nodist_libmytest_la_SOURCES = test.capnp.c++
CLEANFILES = test.capnp.c++

# or: CLEANFILES = $(nodist_libmytest_la_SOURCES)
```